# NSFetchedResultsController - track changes only to a subset of the properties

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

The NSFetchedResultsController monitors the changes to the whole managed object that's keeping track of. Whenever any property get modified in the current context, for instance

```
– controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:
```

gets called. This of course affect the performance of the UITableView hooked to the FRC, if the changes happen really frequently.

Is it possible to keep track then of only some properties? I need this to take advantage of the FRC for those changes that are more sporadic in time, without necessarily receiving notifications each time frequently changing attributes are modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.
If you need finer grain observation, just separate the properties to a different entity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you are getting calls to this delegate method with the change type NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate, because of changes to the underlying objects which are not relevant to how you display the data. Is this correct?

As the previous answer said, it is not possible to configure the FRC so that it ignores certain properties.

My first question would be, what exactly is the performance bottleneck? Updating will only happen for cells which are currently visible, so I'm wondering how frequently updates happen or how complex your cells are in order for this to cause performance problems?

In order to ignore changes which do not affect the way cells are displayed I would make the cells smarter. I.e. when you get the change notification and you reconfigure the cell, the cell itself could check if any relevant values have actually changed or not. If not, you can just ignore the update.

Comment: Basically I have a model entity representing a download, with information like bytes read, total bytes and so on. It's the managed object itself taking care of initiating the download, resuming, updating progress values and so on, and of course each time that this happens, an update is triggered. On my cells I want to show the progress and the current state of each download (paused, completed, failed...). I start thinking that splitting the entity in 2 parts as @Dan Shelly suggested is the only solution, and handle the progress via notifications to the cells directly maybe

Comment: Don't you need to be notified about each change in the state of the download and the progress value if you want to show this in your cell? From what I understand from your comment you need all the notifications the FRC is giving you in order to update the cells with the current progress status? What am I missing? :)

Comment: In *theory*, you are missing nothing. And that's exactly what I did. But getting so many updates via FRC, for some reason knocks down the smoothness of the table. When I'm scrolling and getting frequent updates, the scroll looks really jerky. And I think that somewhere in the doc is also stated that you should use FRC for sporadic updates, maybe for this reason..

Comment: I'm still wondering what _frequent_ means. Like 1/s, 10/s, 100/s? Then the next question would be what causes the performance problems. Do you still see performance issues when you ignore the FRC delegate call (just don't update the cell)? If not, how does your cell look like? Maybe updating the cell can be sped up. Additionally you can decide to only update a cell if the change in e.g. the progress value is greater than a certain threshold which matters for displaying.

Comment: Well, updating the cell in not a problem per-se I guess. I just increase the progress of the progress bar. I believe it's really just FRC doing stuff too frequently, and with frequently i mean even more times in a second (there is a stream open for download, every time I get some bytes, I update). And then, if I do nothing in the FRC update method (no cell update), the problem is still there, so I really guess something happens under the hood. And if I let the updates be fired every 5 seconds, I notice a small jerkiness happening every 5 seconds. I guess it's really the FRS the issue

Comment: Hmm interesting. How does your core data stack setup look like - do the changes on the download objects happen in the main thread managed object context? How often do you save this context? That could be a reason for the stuttering, because there is blocking disk i/o involved.

Comment: I have to check it again and review it. I'll get back to you as soon as I have more information

Comment: So, I've revamped a bit the whole architecture. I'm using core data multithreaded now. On the main thread I just merge the contexts when save. Still the same problem. I noticed that in principle [tableView beginUpdates] and [tableView endUpates] in the FRC delegates (controllerWillChangeContent and controllerDidChangeContent) cause the table to perform badly, if they get called for every chunk of data received...

Comment: @FlorianKugler I have the same problem, mine is a list view controller and detail view controller setup. In the list VC, I display name alone from Person entity, however when the person's age changes, the cell gets updated causing to update (flicker) but there are no visual changes to the user. Wonder what would be a better way ?